# parallel computing about sorted array's index

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I met a problem about using cuda to compute the first index about the member in one sorted array, for example, if one sorted array is given [1,1,2,2,5,5,5], I need to return 0(the first index of 1), 2(the first index of 2), 4(the first index of 5). is there some parallel method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible method to perform this operation would be:

1. use an [adjacent difference](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html) methodology (each parallel thread looks at its element and its neighbor) to identify the start of each sub-sequence.  Elements which have no difference as compared to their neighbors are not the start of a sub-sequence.  Elements which are different from their neighbors represent the start (or end, or start+end) of a sub-sequence.
2. Once the start of each sub-sequence is identified, use a [stream compaction](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) method to reduce the given sequence to just the sequence of elements that represent the start of each sub-sequence.   Stream compaction can also be done in parallel, and a typical approach would involve use of a parallel prefix sum to identify destination addresses for each element in the compacted sequence.

The first part of the above algorithm would be fairly easy to write CUDA code directly for.  The second part would be a little more involved because a [parallel prefix sum](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) is a little bit more complicated to write.  Furthermore, for algorithms like parallel prefix sum, parallel reduction, sorting, etc. I would *never* recommend that someone write these from scratch.  You should always use a library implementation if possible.

Therefore, [the thrust library](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), built on top of CUDA, presents a set of routines allowing a straightforward approach to prototype such a solution:

```
$ cat t1200.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int mytype;

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  mytype data[] = {1,1,2,2,5,5,5};
  int dsize = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);

  thrust::device_vector<mytype> d_data(data, data+dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> d_diffs(dsize);
  thrust::adjacent_difference(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d_diffs.begin());
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(dsize);
  int rsize = thrust::copy_if(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(dsize), d_diffs.begin(), d_result.begin(), _1 > 0) - d_result.begin();
  thrust::copy_n(d_result.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t1200 t1200.cu
$ ./t1200
0,2,4,
$
```

There are various corner cases that might need to be handled depending on the exact composition of your input data.  The above code is just a simple example to demonstrate a possible method.  For example, if the first element in your sorted sequence is zero or negative, then the above code would need to be modified slightly.  Since the first element of your input data is *always* the start of a sub-sequence, this could be trivially handled with an extra line of code that sets the first element of `d_diffs` to a positive value, always, immediately before the `copy_if` usage.

Comment: I was thinking about scan using the sorted data as the key. that might be faster than this